# Determinant of an $A_n$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

We have:
For $n ∈ N$ let $A_n ∈ R^{n×n}$

$A_n = \begin{pmatrix}
2&{-1}&0&{...}&...&0\\-1&2&-1&...&...&...\\0&-1&2&...&...&...\\...&...&...&...&...&...\\...&...&...&2&-1&0\\...&...&...&-1&2&-1\\0&...&...&0&-1&2&\\
\end{pmatrix}$

In this case to calculate the determinant n=1 would it be the matrix
$A_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
2&{-1}&0\\-1&2&-1\\0&-1&2\end{pmatrix}$

n=2
$A_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
2&{-1}&0&2&{-1}&0\\-1&2&-1&-1&2&-1\\0&-1&2&0&-1&2\\2&{-1}&0&2&{-1}&0\\-1&2&-1-&1&2&-1\\0&-1&2&0&-1&2\end{pmatrix}$

n=3
$A_3 = \begin{pmatrix}
2&{-1}&0&2&2&{-1}&0&{-1}&0\\-1&2&-1&-1&2&-1&-1&2&-1\\0&-1&2&0&-1&2&0&-1&2\\2&{-1}&0&2&{-1}&0&2&{-1}&0\\-1&2&-1-&1&2&-1&-1&2&-1\\0&-1&2&0&-1&2&0&-1&2\\2&{-1}&0&2&{-1}&0&2&{-1}&0\\-1&2&-1-&1&2&-1&-1&2&-1\\0&-1&2&0&-1&2&0&-1&2\end{pmatrix}$

And so on?

Comment: Your $A_n$ looks tridiagonal $n\times n$, but your $A_1, A_2, A_3$ examples are $3n\times 3n$ and circulant. I think you should fix this, and make it clear which one it is, as it will fundamentally affect the result.

Comment: An should be tridiagonal, Im not sure how to put the diagonal dots

Comment: I put it as I understand, that is my main question is this correct? If not, what is? And why?

Comment: The matrix $A_n$ is supposed to have $n$ lines & $n$ columns, which gives: $A_1=(2)$, then $A_2=\begin{pmatrix}2&-1\\ -1&2\end{pmatrix}$,
$A_3=\begin{pmatrix}2&-1&0\\ -1&2&0\\ 0&-1&2\end{pmatrix}$,
$A_4=\begin{pmatrix}2&-1&0&0\\ -1&2&-1&0\\ 0&-1&2&0\\0&0&-1&2\end{pmatrix}$,
etc. More generally you have a principal diagonal filled with $2$'s, this diagonal is surrounded by sup and a sub-diagonals filled with $-1$'s, and the rest of the matrix is filled with $0$'s.

Comment: Oooooh I thought that bc the 3×3 at the top left and bottom right repeated as this bulk so the further we go the more it repeats, thank you @jp boucheron!!!

Comment: @Klarko4 You're welcome. Now it's up to you for the determinant. By the way I realized —too late for editing!— that **I made a typo above**: the *second line* for $A_3$ and *third line* for $A_4$ should end with a $-1$ instead of a $0$… (one more copy-and-paste drama).

Comment: All good, again, thank you for taking the time to explain :D